# Regular Expression not matching a string as expected

Tags: c#, regex

I have this regular expression:

```
^((([hH][tT][tT][pP][sS]?|[fF][tT][pP])\:\/\/)?([\w\.\-]+(\:[\w\.\&%\$\-]+)*@)?((([^\s\(\)\<\>\\\""\.\[\]\,@;:]+)(\.[^\s\(\)\<\>\\\""\.\[\]\,@;:]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}))|((([01]?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}([01]?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])))(\b\:(6553[0-5]|655[0-2]\d|65[0-4]\d{2}|6[0-4]\d{3}|[1-5]\d{4}|[1-9]\d{0,3}|0)\b)?((\/[^\/][\w\.\,\?\'\\\/\+&%\$#\=~_\-@]*)*[^\.\,\?\""\'\(\)\[\]!;<>{}\s\x7F-\xFF])?)$
```

It works for the most part, but it doesn't match `localhost:8888`.

How can I modify this expression to match `localhost:8888`?

Comment: That's huge! What pattern are you trying to match?

Comment: A collection of different URLs. It works, minus the string I mentioned in the OP.

Comment: Why not go with `try {Uri myUri = new Uri(myString);}`?

Comment: Because that won't meet my requirements, nor did I ask about matching URIs. To be fair, my question was specific.

Comment: Would it be easier to maintain/add to this code by using many regexes instead of one?

Comment: [Two problems...](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html)

Comment: Are you sure this isn't some kind of sick joke? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you were missing was an optional (`?`) on the top-level domain.

```
^((([hH][tT][tT][pP][sS]?|[fF][tT][pP])\:\/\/)?([\w\.\-]+(\:[\w\.\&%\$\-]+)*@)?((([^\s\(\)\<\>\\\""\.\[\]\,@;:]+)(\.[^\s\(\)\<\>\\\""\.\[\]\,@;:]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})?)|((([01]?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}([01]?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])))(\b\:(6553[0-5]|655[0-2]\d|65[0-4]\d{2}|6[0-4]\d{3}|[1-5]\d{4}|[1-9]\d{0,3}|0)\b)?((\/[^\/][\w\.\,\?\'\\\/\+&%\$#\=~_\-@]*)*[^\.\,\?\""\'\(\)\[\]!;<>{}\s\x7F-\xFF])?)$
```

Matches a few examples, including the one you want:

http://www.rexfiddle.net/6tWa1Wl

I would **very strongly** suggest that you use the built-in [`Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class in .NET though, as it handles all of this parsing and validation for you (better than any regex ever could). It was designed to be versatile, there is very little you can't do with it if you're dealing with any sort of URI (as it appears you are), and I'm pretty sure it's going to be faster than Regex, too.

Comment: +1 for using URI class. This is an elaborate and ugly Regex that I would hate to see in code if I had to debug it.

Comment: How would you recommend that I use the `Uri` class when validating an ASP.Net MVC 4 ViewModel property? My current solution uses `[RegularExpression("...")]` as a property attribute.

Comment: Assuming you are using Data Annotations, there is a [`Url`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.urlattribute.aspx) attribute you can use to validate URLs. If that doesn't suit your needs, write your own data validator (There are lots of tutorials on Google about how to do this).